# Weird hexadecimal format

Tags: c++, c, file-io, hex, decimal

Following hexdump shows some data made by device i have on my hands. It stores year, month, day, hour, minute, seconds, and lenght in weird way for me (4 bytes marks for single digit in reverse order).

```
de 07 00 00 01 00 00 00  16 00 00 00 10 00 00 00
24 00 00 00 1d 00 00 00  15 00 00 00 X X X X
```

For example:
Year is marked as "000007de" aka 0x07de (=2014). Now; problem i am having is how to properly handle this in c/c++. (first 4 bytes)

How do i read those 4 bytes with "reverse" order to make proper hexadecimal for handling afterwards with like ints/longs?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: Read them into an `int32_t` and use `ntohl()`

Answer (score 1):

If you read the value as `int` on the same architecture it has been generated with then you don't need to do anything, as this is the natural format for your system.

You only need to do something about this if you want to read it on a different architecture, with a different binary format.

So you can read it simply with

```
 int32_t n;
 fread(&n, sizeof int32_t, 1, FILE);
```

Of course the file has to be opened in binary mode and you need a 32 bit int.

Answer (score 0):

If you read it in the reverse order, you can then change the endianness with something like:

```
uint32_t before = 0xde070000;
uint32_t after = ((before<<24) & 0xff000000) |
                 ((before<<8)  & 0xff0000)   |
                 ((before>>8)  & 0xff00)     |
                 ((before>>24) & 0xff);
```

Edit: as pointed out in comments, this is only defined for unsigned 32-bits conversions.

Comment: This performs left-shifts on a signed integer, which has behavior not defined by the C standard when there is overflow or the value is negative, and right-shifts on a signed integer, which has implementation-defined behavior.

Comment: You're right, this is only defined for unsigned 32-bits conversions.